# listview with image taken from a specified folder

Tags: android, image, listview

I have an app in which a listview is populated from a db.

from this db i take a text and a string containing a folder, like /sd-card/my-folder/image.jpg

I need to create a listview with the image and the text.

I know all about listview adapter and other things... but I don't know how to put this image, because i don't have the id (such as `getResources().getIdentifier("foto_"+Integer.parseInt(data_mio.getString(id_immagine)), "drawable", getPackageName()))`

but only the string.... the max that I can get is a drawable :-|

```
        String[] from = new String[] {"photo","description"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.list_image,R.id.list_content};
        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.lista, data_db, from, to); 
        list_inventario.setAdapter(adapter);
```

any help?

Comment: i think its easy to use a customised adapter which extends a BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

listView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/path_to_file"))

Comment: i've edited the first post.
with my simple adapter, i can do it? or i must use the other?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("the path");

yourview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the path to the file, you can open it very easily with the standard Java I/O classes (assuming it is stored on the SD card, for internal storage you will need to use a different method).

You can then create a drawable like so:

```
FileInputStream readFile = new FileInputStream("/sd-card/my-folder/image.jpg");
Drawable yourDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(readFile, "image.jpg");
```

Then you can use the Drawable as you normally would.

If the path to the image is an internal storage path, you can create the Drawable this way:

```
Drawable yourDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("/my-folder/image.jpg"), "image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

i've founded the solution by myself! Very simple!

```
        String[] from = new String[] {"foto","descrizione"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.prova,R.id.list_content};
        final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.lista, data_db, from, to); 
        list_inventario.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the image work correctly.
this is satisfaction :-)

Comment: happy to know that u solved the solution of your own. Happy coding